# return product ids and their count even if there is no variant for them in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables:

```
table_products - product_id, pname
variants - vid, vname
table_product_varients - product_id, vid
```

i want to get the count for product variants for all the products, and if there is no variant for a product it should give count as 0.

This is my query:

```
SELECT P.product_id, count(*) AS count
FROM table_product_varients AS PV
LEFT JOIN table_products AS P ON PV.product_id = P.product_id
GROUP BY P.product_id
ORDER BY P.product_id ASC
```

But this is not giving products for which there is no variants.

can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have put the `table_products` table to the `left`.
Also you should have counted `PV.product_id`.

```
SELECT 
P.product_id, 
count(PV.product_id) AS count
FROM table_products AS P 
LEFT JOIN table_product_varients AS PV ON PV.product_id = P.product_id
GROUP BY P.product_id
ORDER BY P.product_id ASC;
```

**Note:** For those products which don't have corresponding entry in `table_products_varients` table you will get `NULL` value of `PV.product_id`. Thus `COUNT(NULL)` actually returns `0`

**Some subtleties regarding `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT COUNT(0);   Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(-1);  Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(NULL); Result: 0

SELECT COUNT(71); Result: 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0)

Comment: I tried this query. But still it is not returning any rows for which there is no variants

Comment: I've made a small change after that. Could you please try again? If you get the same result not as expected then please share an sql fiddle.

Comment: same result. 1- 1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-7, 7-1 ...Basically i need 1- 1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-7, 5-0, 6-0 , 7-1.

Comment: Could you please share an sql fiddle with the sample data?

Comment: Can you tell me which table contains all the products? Is it `table_products`?